# Django query optimization: find a list of objects based on a many-to-one to a many-to-many

Tags: python, sql, django

I have an ugly loop that is operating as a band-aid in Django that I'd like to optimize into a join. I've broken it down to the most basic structure to help simplify the problem. I'm hoping someone else has run into something like this before -- if not, I'll share the answer when I finally fix it.

To summarize

- **Object A** has a non-symmetrical, many-to-many relationship with itself.
- **Object B** has a many-to-one relationship with Object A.
- Given an *ObjectB*, I need a set of other *ObjectBs* that are the children of the *ObjectAs* that are associated with our *ObjectB's* parent *ObjectA*.

I'm sure someone with more database experience could phrase that better (leave a comment if you have a better description of this association).

Here is a bare bones example of the structure I'm working with in Django, and the sort of loop that's running:

```py
class ObjectA(models.Model):
    object_a_rules = models.ManyToManyField("self", symmetrical=False, through='ObjectARule')

class ObjectARule(models.Model):
    object_a_one = models.ForeignKey(ObjectA, related_name="object_a_before")
    object_a_two = models.ForeignKey(ObjectA, related_name="object_a_after")

class ObjectB(models.Model):
    object_a_association = models.ForeignKey(ObjectA)

    def that_annoying_loop_i_mentioned(self):
        object_a_rules_list = ObjectARule.objects.filter(object_a_one = self.object_a_association)
        #A list of all of the ObjectARules that have the ObjectA this ObjectB is associated with
        #as the first half of the many-to-many relationship.

        object_b_list = ObjectB.objects.all()
        #A list of all of the ObjectBs, may also be a filtered list

        for object_a_rule in object_a_rules_list:
            for object_b in object_b_list:
                if (object_a_rule.object_a_two == object_b.object_a_association):
                #if the second half of ObjectARule is the ObjectA of
                #the ObjectB in this list, then do something with that ObjectB.
                pass
```

How could Django get a list of ObjectBs through a join, so this painfully inefficient loop wouldn't have to run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Given an ObjectB, I need a set of
>   other ObjectBs that are the children
>   of the ObjectAs that are associated
>   with our ObjectB's parent ObjectA.

If `objb` is the ObjectB you are given, you could do this as follows:

```
objects = ObjectB.objects.filter(object_a_association__object_a_rules=objb.object_a_association)
```

or alternatively,

```
objects = ObjectB.objects.filter(object_a_association__object_a_rules__objectb_set=objb)
```

See also [Lookups that span relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer -- I definitely need to become more familiar with Django's QuerySet.